# How to handle large number that is bigger than BigInteger in java?

Tags: java, biginteger, largenumber

**input:**

```
BigInteger l = BigInteger.valueOf(111111111111111110);
```

**compiler error message**

> Integer number too large

My objective is to continuously decrement of the given large number till a certain value(say K).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How is the input converted to BigInteger?

Comment: What do you mean by "bigger than BigInteger"?

Comment: "How to handle large number that is bigger than BigInteger in java?" the only limit to BigInteger is your RAM. so there is no chance that your number is larger than what a BigInteger can hold.

Comment: BigInteger l = BigInteger.valueOf(111111111111111110); by this way input it converted to biginteger.

Comment: `111111111111111110` is bigger than max `int` value. Pass it as String `new BigInteger("111111111111111110")`

Comment: @Pshemo  now I'm clear with BigInteger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Integer number too large

the reason why it's giving an error is because the type that you've passed into the argument of the `valueOf(...)` is an `int` (this is the default type unless you specify otherwise) which has a limit, and you've exceeded this limit hence the error.

```
BigInteger l = BigInteger.valueOf(111111111111111110); // argument is int, so it will give a compiler error
```

use a `long` argument instead.

```
BigInteger value = BigInteger.valueOf(111111111111111110L);
```

or use a `string` argument.

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("111111111111111110");
```

Comment: Please use `L` to represent `long` suffix. `L` is easier to read than `l` which can be interpreted as `1` with some fonts.

Comment: @Pshemo sure thing. :)